ros2 topic commands equivalent to rostopic commands
I have used ros1 before like 5 years ago and now I am trying to use ROS2 for my current work and it seems like some of the previous commands are not available for ROS2 foxy or maybe I am unaware of it. I am trying following:

I am trying to see only headers for some topics. In ROS1, I use


$ rostopic echo /topic/header

but in ros2,

$ ros2 topic echo /topic/header

doesnot work. Example in ros2:


I want to see for example only one message using -n1 command. Eg


rostopic echo -n1 /topic

This also does not work with ros2 foxy. Example in ROS2 foxy:

Can someone provide equivalent to these? Thanks

Please edit your question to show what "doesn't work." Please include both how you set up your system as well as what the errors are that you get.  Nominally you have the right command mapping.

Added relevent error/warning message that one get while using ROS2/foxy


I want to see for example only one message using -n1 command. Eg
rostopic echo -n1 /topic
This also does not work with ros2 foxy.

AFIK this is not possible with foxy or galactic - only with humble:
ros2 topic echo --once /scan

There was a PR for this, perhaps it works on the latest Foxy.

Thanks for the hint. On doing research, I also found "--field" flag for (1) and "--once" flag for (2). But unfortunately both do not work with foxy that I have.
